# bash: !.url": event not found while extracting filenames

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I am trying to extract filenames with `.url` extension using `$name =~ s/\.url$//;`. However, some of the names contain an exclamation mark just before the extension, e.g.:

```
"for example-this!.url" "and-something-else!.url"
```

This causes perl to emit an error and stop running:

```
bash: !.url": event not found
```

Is there a way to overcome this problem? Below shows part of the relevant code that I am using:

```
foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
 my (undef, $dir, $name) = File::Spec->splitpath($f);
 $name =~ s/\.url$//;
```

Comment: Single quote filenames?

Comment: @Koterpillar, I can't because some filenames already contain single quotes.

Comment: Are there any filenames which contain double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error` that you're getting happens when history expansion is enabled (which is the default).

In order to disable, do

```
set +o histexpand
```

on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not from perl but from the bash. You may want to store the filenames in a file and read them from there. Note that this problem only occurs when the bash is parsing your command line input. When the script reads filenames from a file, pipe, etc. there won't be any problem.

Comment: I see.. Sorry, I just start learning perl. Can you show me how to port it over to the @ARGV variable. Thanks.